# JavaScript capture MP3 playback duration and Countdown to submit at the end

Tags: javascript

I Have a object that is definite the duration of a media from this tag :

```
<span class="mejs-duration">00:50</span>
```

I try to capture the time to show the button to skip like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">var seconds = getElementsByClassName("mejs-duration")[0] ;  function decreaseTime(){ document.frm.submit.value=seconds; seconds--; if(seconds<0){ document.frm.submit.value='Submit'; document.frm.submit.disabled=false; return true; } setTimeout('decreaseTime()',1000); } window.onload = function() { document.frm.submit.value=seconds; setTimeout('decreaseTime()',1000); } </script><form name="frm" action="" metod="link"> <input type="submit" name="submit" disabled /> </form>
```

But I have this error :
Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsByClassName is not defined
    at ....

Where I mistake ?

Thank You in advance for Help me.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` is a method on the `document` object and on HTML Element Node objects. It is not a global.

Comment: to explain it easier: use document.getElementsByClassName to make it work